# Using Regex to match if a specific character occurs a specific number of times

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to check if a string, *str*, contains **at least** two numbers and **exactly** two of any of the following symbols: '!','@','#','$','%','&','*'.

What seems to be happening is that I'm only matching if they occur consecutively and not in total. How do I fix this?

```
str = 'a1b2c$3d#4e!f@ghi0'

sym = '[!@#$%&*]{2}'
num = '[0-9]{2,}'

for char in str:
    if re.search(sym, str):
        if re.search(num, str):
            print('match!')
        else:
            print('no matches!')
```

Comment: You could use a pattern like `^(?=.*([!@#$%&*]).*\1)(?=\D*\d\D*\d).+` https://regex101.com/r/T90MyU/1

Comment: Try with sym = "^(.*?[!@#$%&*].*?){2}$" and num = "^(.*?\\d.*?){2,}$";

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'm still getting familiar with metacharacters in Regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 2 patterns, you don't have to loop to check every character. In `sym` You can check if the string has exactly 2 of the listed characters.

In `num` you can match at least 2 digits.

```
import re

str = 'test$test$test123'

sym = r'^[^!@#$%&*\r\n]*[!@#$%&*][^!@#$%&*\r\n]*[!@#$%&*][^!@#$%&*\r\n]*\Z'
num = r'^[^\d\r\n]*\d[^\d\r\n]*\d'

if re.search(sym, str) and re.search(num, str):
    print('match!')
else:
    print('no matches!')
```

---

You might also use a single pattern with re.match

```
^(?=[^\d\r\n]*\d[^\d\r\n]*\d)[^!@#$%&*\r\n]*[!@#$%&*][^!@#$%&*\r\n]*[!@#$%&*][^!@#$%&*\r\n]*\Z
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[^\d\r\n]*\d[^\d\r\n]*\d)` Positive lookahead, assert 2 digits
- `[^!@#$%&*\r\n]*[!@#$%&*][^!@#$%&*\r\n]*[!@#$%&*][^!@#$%&*\r\n]*` Match exactly 2 of any of the listed characters
- `\Z` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zi7SwG/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mNGNE2)

```
import re

str = 'test$test$test123'
pattern = r'(?=[^\d\r\n]*\d[^\d\r\n]*\d)[^!@#$%&*\r\n]*[!@#$%&*][^!@#$%&*\r\n]*[!@#$%&*][^!@#$%&*\r\n]*\Z'
if re.match(pattern, str):
    print('match!')
else:
    print('no matches!')
```

---

Without using a regex, one option is to count the occurrences of a digit and special chars:

```
s = 'test$test$test123'
specialChars = "!@#$%&*"
num = 0
sym = 0

for char in s:
    if char.isdigit():
        num += 1
    if char in specialChars:
        sym += 1

if num > 1 and sym == 2:
    print("Match")
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Xmv4Qa)